# How padding char using xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want padding the data with extra space(any char) using XSL version 1.0.

```
Name field max chars length is 10 (length must be dyanamic) chars.

Need to transfer data using XSL.

In XML:
<emp>
<name>Test</name>
</emp>

Expected Output : 
<emp>
<name>Test******</name>
</emp>

Please let me know if anyone have any solution.

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
substring(concat($yourstring, '**********'), 1, 10)
```

Example using your input:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '**********'), 1, 10)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<emp>
   <name>Test******</name>
</emp>
```

---

Alternatively, if your processor supports it, you could use the EXSLT [str:align()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/align/index.html) function - possibly in conjunction with the [str:padding()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/padding/index.html) function to create the padding string dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Input.xml**
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
<text>1234567</text>
</Data>

**StringPadding.xsl**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="/Data"><xsl:variable name="new-str" select="//Data/text"></xsl:variable>
After Padding= <xsl:call-template name="str-pad"><xsl:with-param name="string" select="$new-str"/><xsl:with-param name="str-length" select="10" /></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="str-pad">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:param name="pad-char" select="'*'"/>
<xsl:param name="str-length" />
<xsl:value-of select="'  '"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length($string) = $str-length">
<xsl:value-of select="$string" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:call-template name="str-pad">
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat($string,$pad-char)" />
<xsl:with-param name="pad-char" select="$pad-char" />
<xsl:with-param name="str-length" select="$str-length" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output : After Padding = 1234567***

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:function name="functx:pad-string-to-length" as="xs:string"
              xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:param name="stringToPad" as="xs:string?"/>
  <xsl:param name="padChar" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="
   substring(
     string-join (
       ($stringToPad, for $i in (1 to $length) return $padChar)
       ,'')
    ,1,$length)
 "/>

</xsl:function>
```

**For example :** 
functx:pad-string-to-length('Ans', '*', 5) 
**Output :** Ans**

Comment: This is not an XSLT 1.0 solution.